# Angular Firestore - Browser Freezes when updating via AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a mat table that is connected to a firestore database via the angularfire method.
and thru this, I can manage to get data (20K records) and load it to a list tag via a click event handler

HTML

```
//Event Handler on Mat Table
(click)="onRowsClicked(row)"

// part of the list tag where the data is passed for editing using template directives
           <li>Customer Name:
              <input 
                  type="text" 
                  name="customerName"
                  *ngIf='customerDetails'
                  value="{{customerDetails.customerName}}"
                  [(ngModel)]="customerDetails.customerName" >

            </li>
             <li>Rate:
              <select  
              class="select-drop" 
              name="rate" 
              id="rate_id" 
              *ngIf='customerDetails'
              value ="{{customerDetails.customerRate}}"
              [(ngModel)]="customerDetails.customerRate">
              <option *ngFor="let rateCodeList of rateCodeList" 
              value="{{rateCodeList.rateValue}}">{{rateCodeList.rateValue}}</option>
              </select>

            </li>
```

TS

```
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../../models/customer.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-members',
  templateUrl: './members.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./members.component.scss']
})


export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {


   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
   displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'customerAccountNo', 
    'customerNo', 
    'customerName', 
    'customerAddress',
    'customerZone',
     'customerSeqNo'];
  
  
  constructor(

    private customerService: CustomerService,
  

  ) { 
    

  }
  
  customerList:Customer[];
  customerDetails: Customer;

  

  // 
  ngOnInit(): void {

    }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.customerService.getCustomer().subscribe(custObs => {
     this.customerList = custObs;
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(custObs);
   
    }
    
  }

 


   onRowsClicked(rows: Customer) {
   this.customerDetails = rows;
   } 
  
 updateDetails() {
    this.customerService.updateCustomer(this.customerDetails);
  }



}
```

Service TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CustomerService {
  customerCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection <Customer>;
  customerDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument <Customer>;
  customers: Observable<Customer[]>;

   constructor(
    public angularFireStore: AngularFirestore

  ) 
  {}

    getCustomer() {
    this.customerCollection = this.angularFireStore.collection('customer');
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map( a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Customer;
        data.id=a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })

    }))
    return this.customers;
  }

  updateCustomer (custcol : Customer) {
    this.customerDoc = this.angularFireStore.doc(`customer/${custcol.id}`);
    this.customerDoc.update(custcol);
  }


}
```

Model.ts

```
export class Customer {
    id?: string;
    customerNo: string;
    customerAccountNo: string;
    customerName: string;
    customerAddress: string;
    customerContactNo: string;
    customerEmail: string;
    customerSeqNo: string;
    customerMeterNo: string;
    customerRate: string;;
    customerStatus: string;
    customerZone: string;
    customerPa: string;
    customerSeptage: number;
    customerPipe: string;
    customerContractNo: string;
    customerDeposit: string;
    customerRsNumber: string;
    customerClassification: string;
    customerSaddleSize: string;
    installDate: string;
    connectionDate: string;
    customerBranch: string;
    startReading: string;
}
```

Please see image
[image]

querying and adding data is not a problem, however whenever I update my data and call an update thru my service it freezes and becomes like this.

[image]

there's no error showing up, after a few minutes it will come back again but then the following will show on my console

[image]

Comment: I think the error resides while you are fetching a single document from the collection to update it, in updateCustomer method. Can you modify your code like below?

Comment: `export class CustomerService{
 Private customerDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>;
 customerCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection <Customer>;
 customers: Observable<Customer[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.customerCollection = afs.collection<Customer>(‘customer’);
    this.customerDoc = afs.doc<Customer>(‘customer/1');
  }
    updateCustomer(custcol: Customer) {
    this.customerDoc.update(custcol);
  }
}`

Comment: Reference : https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md
Also have a look at this [stack blitz code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lymeyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), where they have used valueChanges and tap method for single document fetch.

Comment: Thank you it seems that using snapshotchanges overr valuechanges affects since I'm just modifying the object data itself.

Comment: Did it work for you? Can I post my comments as a solution to your question then.. It will help others facing the same issue get to a resolution faster as they would have this as a reference.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra we're still checking for now, i'll give you an update within the day. but it seems it solves one of the errors but not yet the freezing part. will be making changes on some codes today.

Comment: Okay sure. Let me know.

Comment: any update ? Were you able to solve this with the code change?